# Not typical "To Sign in Remotely, You Need the Right to Sign in Through Remote Desktop Service" issue

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I have the "To Sign in Remotely, You Need the Right to Sign in Through Remote Desktop Service" problem. But it is not that simple.

When I added a new user as a domain user, automatically the use became a member of the  “Remote Desktop Users” group and also the "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services" policy was set correctly.

The thing is, once I log in with whatever existing domain user, then I can switch to or log out/in with the new domain user.

But, if I restart the Windows 10 machine, I cannot log in with the new domain user.
So, I have to log in with any existing domain user then switch to or log out/in with the new domain user.

As long as I don't turn off the Windows machine, I don't have the error message.

Anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found it was the "Enhanced session" option.
If I turn it off, I can log in without any error.